# How should I store the data of the notes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, github-pages, google-keep

I made this lite version google keep app in react and was wondering how you personally would go about storing the notes data, so that anyone entering the page sees the same notes, and have the same editing capabilities(deleting the notes).

Right now it only stores till refreshed.
https://audunlk.github.io/googlekeep/

Thank you.

Comment: I think better you use nosql with listener since it's require multi user CRUD.

Comment: Will def look into this. Thank you for taking your time to bring your input

Answer (score 0):

Some JSON fill to store data and later edit it or delete it. or firebase real-time database

Comment: Thank youu, im gonna try firebase and see how far i get, ill lean on json if i pull all my hair out.

Comment: Firebase's real-time database is easy to use just google some tutorials about it!! You will find a lot out there.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, might aswell learn it now :) its usually am easy choice once multiple people suggest the same solution

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to work with REST you could try [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

If you want a simple way, json would do the trick too. But if you want to have user auth at a later point you can rely on the firebase auth and would not need to implement your own.

Comment: Thank you, i am a complete new befinner, but since you suggest firebase to be the optimal choice, thats proberbly what im gonna try figuring out :)